# Can't pass data between View Controller and Model

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

There is UIAlertController with text field in my View Controller. When user enter name of the city, this data must be transmitted to Model, when I get coordinates of this city. But I can't to pass name of the city from View Controller to Model

My UIAlertController:

```
class MainScrenenViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var delegate: ILocationGroup?

    @objc func locationButtonTap() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add city", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let addButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { action in
           
            self.delegate?.addLocation(alert.textFields?.first?.text ?? "No City")
            
        }
        
        alert.addAction(addButton)
        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)
        
        alert.addTextField { textField in
            textField.placeholder = "Your City"
        }
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

My Model:

```
protocol ILocationGroup {
    
    func addLocation(_ name: String)
    
}

class LocationGroup: ILocationGroup {
    
    var mainScreenViewController: MainScrenenViewController?
        
    func addLocation(_ name: String) {
        
        mainScreenViewController?.delegate = self
        
                let url = "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=fd93783b-fe25-4428-8c3b-38b155941c8c&format=json&geocode=\(name)"
                
                guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
                
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            
                    do {
                        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(LocationData.self, from: data)
            
                        
                        print(result.response.geoObjectCollection.metaDataProperty.geocoderResponseMetaData.boundedBy.envelope.lowerCorner)
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("failed to convert \(error)")
                    }
            
                }
                task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to set the reference to `mainScreenViewController` somewhere. It's unclear how both classes are related.

Comment: You also need to set the delegate in the VC.  It's not clear if this is being injected into the VC before it is displayed.   FInally, you decode the json to a local variable in the dataTask compleion block but then don't do anything with it (other than print it) so even if you do manage to get the city data into the URLSession the resultant location value is lost when the closure completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is supposed to be var delegate: LocationGroup()

Also, I wouldn't be calling it delegate because registered delegate is a keyword in swift

https://manasaprema04.medium.com/different-ways-to-pass-data-between-viewcontrollers-views-8b7095e9b1bf